# why does this variable not change in python?

Tags: python

```
gameOver = False

while not(gameOver):
    def startMenu():
        ...

        if (...):
            startGame()
        elif (...):
            Type("Game Over", .2)
            gameOver = True
            print(gameOver) # this prints True but...

    print(gameOver) # ...this prints False.
    startMenu()
```

It's been a while since I've coded in python and I forgot pretty much everything. I wasn't able to find any answers to my question no matter how I rephrase it. It only shows me how to make a variable and temporarily change it to print it such as...

```
str = "hello"
print(str + " world")
```

Comment: You have two different variables named `gameOver`. Once is defined in the global scope, the other is local to `startMenu`.

Comment: hi dirtydan, please include a sample of your data so we can help you. but just out of curiosity, why are you creating a function inside a while loop? you're essentially running the function creation every loop

Comment: [Python function global variables?](//stackoverflow.com/a/10588342)

Comment: hey gorlomi, im putting it in a while loop so that recursion doesn't happen because if i just keep calling the function inside of the function, it's not very efficient.

Comment: hey chepner, thanks for the comment, although im still not understanding then how would i change the public variable inside a local function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variation in scope - i.e. Local and Global scope is the reason behind this confusion.

If you want the changes made inside the function to be reflected in the value of gameOver, then a small work around would be returning the changed value back at the end of the function.

```
gameOver = False

while not(gameOver):
    def startMenu():
        ...

        if (...):
            startGame()
        elif (...):
            Type("Game Over", .2)
            gameOver = True
            print(gameOver) # this prints True but...
        return gameOver

    print(gameOver) # ...this prints False.
    gameOver = startMenu()
    print(gameOver) # ...this prints True (after the function call).
```

And as suggested by Gorlomi, it would be better to place the function definition outside the while loop, as placing the function inside the loop would defeat one of the core purposes of modularity. This variant would be as follows:

```
def startMenu():
        ...

    if (...):
        startGame()
    elif (...):
        Type("Game Over", .2)
        gameOver = True
        print(gameOver) # this prints True but...
    return gameOver

gameOver = False

while not(gameOver):    
    print(gameOver) # ...this prints False.
    gameOver = startMenu()
    print(gameOver) # ...this prints True (after the function call).
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of global and local scope of variables.

```
gameOver = False  # this is global gameOver

while not(gameOver):
    def startMenu():
        ...

        if (...):
            startGame()
        elif (...):
            Type("Game Over", .2)
            global gameOver # add this statement, so that python interpreter wont create a local scope variable 
            gameOver = True
            print(gameOver) # this prints True but...

    print(gameOver) # this will print True
    startMenu()
```